# Удалить файл без подтверждения с++

Tags: c++

При удалении файла через командер, спрашивается подтверждение.
Как удалить такой файл из программы?

```
 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 fs::remove("c:/temp/1.txt");
 }
```

Выдает ошибку при выполнении.

Comment: Нужно догадаться, какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ну исправьте. Что именно? Но ведь и вы не сказали, какая именно ошибка. *-Доктор, у меня что-то болит... - Ну, примите какие-то таблетки...* https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: выдает ошибку file system error: can not remove. В cmd есть ключ удалять без подтверждения. Вот тут бы такой ключ. В общем я вручную изменил атрибуты. Убрал только для чтения.

Comment: Я думаю, что тут вопрос в том, что свою программу нужно запускать с правами администратора

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из вашего ответа в комментарии и судя по пути к удаляемому файлу все становится более менее ясно.
Вы пишите приложение под windows и согласно документации на этой платформе `fs::remove` вызывает WinAPI функцию `DeleteFileW`. В описании которой сказано, что она не может удалить файл, предназначенный только для чтения, и перед этим необходимо снять этот флаг с файла.
Используя стандартную библиотеку плюсов, сделать это можно так:

```
int main()
{
//Даем права на чтение/выполнение/запись файла всем пользователям
 fs::permissions("c:/Temp/1.txt", fs::perms::all);
//Удаляем файл
 fs::remove("c:/temp/1.txt");
}
```